# How to make a conditional statement creating new dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a MultiIndex dataframe for which I would like to create a conditional statement that would say in each specific group of the columns "A" if the value in column "F" is > 0, then, that entire group (of column A) should be copied to a new dataframe (newdf) for further processing.

Here is how two rows of df kind of looks like:

```
  A         B            C          D           E      F   G    H 

 A8374D  []KLJEFSIJSE  some;text   more,text   12.4   4.6   13  X5

         []BKFLKJLJLK  text;some  other,stuff  65.0   6.5   11  Y0
```

...

Here is what I have so far (which doesn't work)

```
for row in df['A']:
   newdf = df['F'].where(df['F'] > 0)
print(newdf)
```

Error message:

```
KeyError: 'A'
```

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: you just might need to create a function and then use apply to implement it to the new dataframe. like this: df.apply(myfunct, axis=1)

Comment: @MEdwin, how would I specify that the function is to be applied in each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess A is one of your multiindex. I would like to make A not as index

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

and then I guess you want to keep A if ***ANY*** of F within group A is > 0

```
df_new = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x.F > 0).any()).to_frame('WANT').reset_index()

df_final = df[df.A.isin(df_new.loc[df_new.WANT == 1,'A'])]
```

If you want to make sure ***ALL*** F values within group A is >0, then change to

```
(x.F > 0).all()
```

Please let me know if you have any other questions. If you like it, please vote me up

Comment: I'm getting a df with the name of the groups (from A) and if they have a value >0 (True/False). But I actually want a new dataframe that would have all the members of each "A" group if any of them has a value >0 on F.

Comment: df_final is the result you want, because i select all data of each "A" group if any F > 0

Comment: I see what you mean. But isn't there a way to get a different df for each group? Because after . this I want to compare the similarity between the strings on "B", and I think it would be easier if each "A" group is in a different df, since it will create multiple comparisons.

Comment: if you really want to create different df for different groups, you can use "exec".                         for group in df_final.A.unique():  exec("df_" + group + " = df_final[df_final.A == group]")       I am not sure if it works but it seems to be weird because you can compare B in one dataframe